# Dropdown menu positions outside of window view

Tags: html, css

I have a `Press Me` button that opens a dropdown menu when pressed. My JavaScript works, but I have the following problem with CSS and HTML:

When you click `Press Me` the dropdown menu opens BUT it is partially not in the visible window. You have to scroll to the right to see the problem.

I tried to use `right: px` with some numbers but now it's not responsive at all.

```js
// NO PROBLEM HERE IN JAVASCRIPT!
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].classList.toggle('show');
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('#verify-name')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    color: red;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
        padding: 14px;
        background-color: yellow;
}
.show {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <div>
        <a id="verify-name" onclick="myFunction()">Press Me</a>

        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <span>Logout</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I tried to use right: px with some numbers but now it's not responsive at all."_ - no, not as long as you use the viewport as the reference point _for_ the absolute positioning. Make `.buttons` the reference point, by giving that one `position: relative`

Comment: Stop using `.matches()` with `event.target`. It's bug prone (understand first what Event.target *is* - before using it). Should be like: `if(!event.target.closest("some_selector")) {`

Comment: Avoid polluting HTML markup with calls to JavaScript functions from inline `on*` handlers attributes. Use Element.addEventListener() instead from *script* instead.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you, going to fix that :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just remove `position: absolute` from `.dropdown-content` class and add `text-align: right;` to `.buttons` class.

```js
// NO PROBLEM HERE IN JAVASCRIPT!
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].classList.toggle('show');
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#verify-name')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  direction: rtl;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 14px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div>
    <a id="verify-name" onclick="myFunction()">Press Me</a>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <span>Logout</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```